# How do I indicate to maven that one dependency provides another?

Tags: maven, guava

After version 11.0.2, Google's guava library switched to Java 6. Fortunately, for those of us stuck on Java 5, they also released a "guava-jdk5" artifact.

Unfortunately, some of my dependencies pull in guava 11.0.2 transitively. Which leaves my project containing both guava-jdk5 and guava.

Normally when I have conflicting versions, I can use the "dependencymanagement" tag to indicate which version to pull in. But since these are two different artifacts, I do not understand how to do this. Ultimately I want to tell maven, guava and guava-jdk5 are the same artifact and I want the 17.0 version of guava-jdk5 to be the one that is used. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Apparently this isn't possible. http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-1977

Answer (score 3):

One easy way is to use a [dependency exclusion](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#Dependency_Exclusions), nutshell from the link:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectA</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-A</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
          <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do that at a global level? I want my java 5 projects to always exclude guava, but then if a java 6 project consumes one of these java 5 projects, then I want guava-jdk5 excluded from that.

Comment: To clarify, I don't want to leak my implementation of my dependencies more than I have to. If a dependency transitively pulls in guava one day, but not in the next version, I may have an unnecessary excludes in my pom. I'd rather just tell maven that for this project I never want to have guava in it or that guava-jdk5 provides guava.

Comment: @JasonThompson, you can specify the exclusion at a global level (root pom.xml) by using [Dependency Management](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management)

Comment: @Vic, I don't want the exclusion to apply to all dependencies, not just certain ones. I did some research, and it looks like what I want to do isn't possible yet: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-1977